# Why does getCurrentListViews().size() equal 2 instead of 3?

Tags: android, testing, robotium

I am writing an android application with a tabbed interface. I am using a `FragmentActivity` with a `ActionBar.Tab` tabs, with each tab displaying a `ListFragment`.

In my test case, I am using `Robotium 3.6` to perform UI interaction, which is needed to test certain aspects of my `fragment's`. Each `fragment` has a separate test method, which tests that the `ListView` for a `fragment` has the same content at a set index (0), as the `ArrayList<String>` which the data is from.

The problem is that while the first two `fragments` pass their respective tests, the final `fragment` does not, with the failure trace being that:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: AbsListView with index 2 is not available!
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Waiter.waitForAndGetView(Waiter.java:362)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Clicker.clickInList(Clicker.java:405)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.clickInList(Solo.java:1004)
at com.******.*******.test.ActivityNavigatorTest.testFragmentSongsList(ActivityNavigatorTest.java:62)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:186)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:537)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1551)
```

Here is the relevant code for the activity being tested:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigator);

    PREFERENCES = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    adapterPager = new AdapterPager(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapterPager);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_fragment_artists).setTag("artists").setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_fragment_albums).setTag("albums").setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_fragment_songs).setTag("songs").setTabListener(this));
}
```

The code for each `ListFragment` is just defining an `ArrayList<String>`, populating it with dummy content and displaying said content with an `ArrayAdapter<String>`. Here is the code for the test case:

```
package com.******.*******.test;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

import com.******.******.ActivityNavigator;
import com.*******.******.FragmentAlbums;
import com.*******.********.FragmentArtists;
import com.*******.******.FragmentSongs;
import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;

public class ActivityNavigatorTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<ActivityNavigator> {

    private Solo solo;

        public ActivityNavigatorTest() {
        super(ActivityNavigator.class);
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    }

    public void testFragmentArtistsList() {     
        solo.assertCurrentActivity("Checking loaded activity is the navigator", ActivityNavigator.class);
        solo.clickOnText("Artists");

        String contentExpected = FragmentArtists.getArtistList().get(0);
        String contentActual = solo.clickInList(0, 0).get(0).getText().toString();

        assertEquals("Testing index 0 has same content in ArrayList and ListView", contentExpected, contentActual);

        int sizeExpected = FragmentArtists.getArtistList().size();
        int sizeActual = solo.getCurrentListViews().get(0).getCount();

        assertEquals("Testing same quantity of data in ArrayList and ListView", sizeExpected, sizeActual);
    }

    public void testFragmentAlbumsList() {
        solo.assertCurrentActivity("Checking loaded activity is the navigator", ActivityNavigator.class);
        solo.clickOnText("Albums");

        String contentExpected = FragmentAlbums.getAlbumList().get(0);
        String contentActual = solo.clickInList(0, 1).get(0).getText().toString();

        assertEquals("Testing index 0 has same content in ArrayList and ListView", contentExpected, contentActual);

        int sizeExpected = FragmentAlbums.getAlbumList().size();
        int sizeActual = solo.getCurrentListViews().get(1).getCount();

        assertEquals("Testing same quantity of data in ArrayList and ListView", sizeExpected, sizeActual);
    }

    public void testFragmentSongsList() {
        solo.assertCurrentActivity("Checking loaded activity is the navigator", ActivityNavigator.class);
        solo.clickOnText("Songs");

        String contentExpected = FragmentSongs.getSongList().get(0);
        String contentActual = solo.clickInList(0, 2).get(0).getText().toString();

        assertEquals("Testing index 0 has same content in ArrayList and ListView", contentExpected, contentActual);

        int sizeExpected = FragmentSongs.getSongList().size();
        int sizeActual = solo.getCurrentListViews().get(2).getCount();

        assertEquals("Testing same quantity of data in ArrayList and ListView", sizeExpected, sizeActual);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a theory but i am not sure it is correct. I believe that your application has each fragemnt displayed one at a time in the view pager right?

Well i believe that possible the first two test cases work by chance more than anything. I believe that only one listview should be being shown at a time and for some reason an extra listview (potentially the one previously seen) is being kept by robotium that means that the count is always two. You can verify this by looking at the hierarchyviewer tool and seeing what listviews are being shown in your application.

The alternative I have for you is to set good ids (or tags/content descriptions) on the different listviews and use these rather than robotiums getCurrentListViews() method which is prone to these sort of issues.

Comment: Absolutely, for some reason it was keeping listview 0 as the one in the first fragment, with listview 1 as the currently viewed fragment's listview.

Comment: Yep, I created an object for each fragment, using the fragment manager to get the appropriate fragment from the activity (by tag). I then changed the contentActual lines to be similar to:

    String contentActual = artists.getListView().getItemAtPosition(0).toString();

and the sizeActual lines to be similar to:

    int sizeActual = artists.getListView().getCount();

Everything seems to be working fine now, thanks for your help :)